# declared http-method in web.xml does not prevent other http-methods

Tags: rest, servlets, web.xml

I want to restrict domains with path /rest/* only for GET-Requests. So I declare it in my web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>All</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    <http-method>GET</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Auth</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>Admin</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

However, when doing a POST-Request to (for example) '/rest/add' then the webcontainer accepts and submit the POST-Request. Why is that so?

Answer (score 0):

That's because the first security-constraint is overwritten by the second one (order matters) which it doesn't have http-methods (If there are NO http-method elements, in the web-resource-collection, it would mean that ALL HTTP Methods are allowed.)

That means tha this code

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>All</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    <http-method>GET</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>
```

is useless

Comment: When navigating to: localhost/section/a.html then I am not allowed to access the resource as declared in web.xml via '/*'. However, I can access 'localhost/rest/myresource' without authentication, as declared via '/rest/*'. So the code is not entire useless.

Comment: I have no http-methods for the second one, but I restrict the access to authenticated roles.

Comment: Does it mean, I should only change the order of the two security-constraints ?

Answer (score 0):

Security constraints are not Overridden. They are additive if the url-patterns of different constraints are the Same. In the example above the url patterns are Different so the First one wins and Posts Are allowed .